# Combining of angular-ui-bootstrap radio button and angular-translate directives

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-translate

I'm using angular-ui-bootstrap radio button [`btn-radio` directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons) together with the  angular-translate i18n [`translate` directive](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/05_using-translate-directive)

The combination of both directives in the `<label>` element makes the btn-radio failing.

I created [a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TqzwpxbyyHff4YB3u3wM?p=preview) to show the btn-radio behaviour

I know there are some issues sharing multiple directives on one dom element and a workaround could be to put the `translate` directive on a sub `span` element, or using the `translate` filter.

So, my question is: is there a way to make these both directives work on the same element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mother tongue is Korean, not English. so, my english is not good.

cause : conflict bootstrap ui and translate library with html element attribute

solution :

1. not using translate with element attribute
2. so, remove element translate attribute.
3. add function to controller for translate language options.

> ```
> ex) 
>   $scope.translate = function(id)
>   {
>       return $translate.instant(id);
>   };
> ```

4. translate using function

> ```
> ex) 
>   <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Left'">{{translate('BTN_A')}}</label>
> ```

5. demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/TPwTan2dSmMVQbNtxpgg?p=preview

   test with blue button.

Answer (score 1):

I just run into the same problem and found a simpler solution without the need to add a function in the controller, but simply using the filter:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Left'">{{'TRANSLATION.KEY' | translate}}</label>
```